# Proper way to handle a form when user provides no inputs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple application that will ask user to enter their start and end address and once they do that they can hit submit and get a list of the next 3 buses/trains to their destinations. However I am not able to handle the case where the user does not enter anything at all and hits submit button.

Here is the code of the simple form

```
   <%= form_tag("/welcome/index", method: "post") do %>
  <div class ="input-group">
  <label>Current Location</label>
  <%= text_field_tag("address", params['address'], :class => 'form-control') %>
</div><br/>
<div class ="input-group">
  <label>Destination Location</label>
  <%= text_field_tag("destaddress", params['destaddress'], :class => 'form-control') %>
  </div>


  <p>
    <br/>
<%= submit_tag "", :value => "Find Buses", :class => "btn btn-default" %>  </p>

<% end %>
```

Here is my controller where i capture user's input and run my logic to give the list of buses.

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  # displays the form, so change the name of the form you have now to new.html.erb
  def new
  end

  # the form will pass to this action to perform logic on longitude and latitude
  def create
    curAddress = params[:address]
    destAddress = params[:destaddress]



    #2 close stops to current location
    @currentList = Stop.by_distance(:origin => curAddress).limit(2)

    if @currentList.length == 0
      flash[:error] = "Somethig is wrong"
    end
    #2 closest stops to destination location
    @destList = Stop.by_distance(:origin => destAddress).limit(2)

    @startIds = Array.new
    2.times do |i|
      @startIds.push(@currentList[i].id)
    end

    @endIds = Array.new
    2.times do |i|
      @endIds.push(@destList[i].id)
    end


    @currentStop = Stop.closest(:origin => curAddress)
    @destinationStop = Stop.closest(:origin => destAddress)



         @timeNow = Time.now.in_time_zone("EST") + 1.hour
    @finalTime = @timeNow.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

    startStopId = @currentStop.first.id
    endStopId = @destinationStop.first.id

     #update it based on succeed
    @cStop = Stop.find(startStopId)
    @dStop = Stop.find(endStopId)




    testMethod(startStopId,endStopId)  


    render :index
  end
```

Above what i do is basically take user's input and then try to use a gem called Geokit to find the two closest stops for some given address by user and store their ids in `@currentList and @destList`

So obviously if the user has not given any input than those 2 lists should be empty right. So using that logic I tried this

```
 if @currentList.length == 0
      flash[:error] = "Somethig is wrong"
    end
```

However I am not able to handle the case where user gives no input. So i was wondering how to handle it? Ideally I want to display a message on the form saying "No inputs entered" so user will retry to enter some input and then hit submit. I am extremely new to ruby on rails , for instance I know in java i could throw exception or something.

Answer (score 1):

Inside of `def create ...`

```
if params[:address].blank? || params[:destaddress].blank? # Checks if it is nil or = ""
  flash[:address_error] = "No address entered"
  render 'new' and return # render new shows the form again, return makes sure we
                          # don't do anything else in the action
                          # you can also do redirect_to, but this will be a little
                          # faster since you have no logic the new action
end
```

You should do this early in the action, so you don't waste time doing other things in the action.

As Sharvy Ahmed mentioned front-end validation is an option as well, and a good idea. An alternative to the HTML5 method he showed is JQuery, which rails uses by default. That might looks something like this.

```
$('form').submit(function() {  //When a form is submitted...
  $('input').each(function() { //Check each input...
    if ($(this).val() == "") { //To see if it is empty...
      alert("Missing address");//Say that it is
      return false;            //Don't submit the form
    }
  });
  return;                      //If we made it this far, all is well, submit the form
});
```

However you should not rely on client side validation, as a user can manually go to the url, bypassing the page with the validation.

Comment: I tried your approach and i never saw flash saying "no address entered " is there something else I need to do?

Comment: There shouldn't be, no. The default layout should handle all flash messages. Unless you changed the default layout `application.html.erb` and how it renders flashes it should work, for example telling it to only show `flash[:error]` you'd need to set the name of the flash in your controller to `[:error]` instead of `[:address_error]`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all validations can be checked in front-end as well as in back-end.

You can use html5 `required` to make the input field mandatory and no one can proceed unless they write something.

```
<%= text_field_tag("address", params['address'], :class => 'form-control'), :required => true %>
```

For back-end validation, you can check if the fields are not `nil` like this:

```
if curAddress && destAddress
  # Do your work here ...
end
```

---

By the way, you will have to refactor the code a lot. A simple refactoring could be declaring a private method to get the nearest location ids by distance like this:

```
private
def nearest_by_distance(address, n)
  Stop.by_distance(:origin => address).limit(n).pluck(:id)
end
```

Then in your `create` action you can do:

```
current_address = params[:address]
destination_address = params[:destaddress]

@start_from_location_ids = nearest_by_distance(current_address, 2)
@end_to_location_ids = nearest_by_distance(destination_address, 2)
```

Hope you got the idea?